# Efficient way to send big data between main process and renderer process

Tags: electron

I need to read/stream big files (giga bytes) and display data in my renderers. The renderer may modify that data which then needs to be passed back to the main process. For security reasons I don't want to do that in the render process, but in the main process and pass the data to the renderer.

What is the most efficient way to pass that data?
Is it possible to have something like a shared memory where there is not even a copy of the data created?

Comment: You can use [`ipcRenderer`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer) and [`ipcMain`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main)

Comment: that will make a copy and IPC calls. Is that the most efficient way?

Comment: Unless you use an nAPI module with `nodeIntegration` activated, you cannot do without IPC calls and copied data. What is the issue with copying the data when passing it to the renderer ? If the passed data is not referenced anymore it will be dropped in the memory anyway.

Comment: The issue is about copying the gigabyes of data from process to process which I would like to avoid very much. Thank you for pointing out N-API. I wasn't aware of that. However, for security reasons I was also trying to avoid to turn of nodeIntegration. Seems to be difficult to get both.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a bit late, but this is what I did for loading large binary files from the local file system:

I added a very basic web server to the main process, and the renderer requests the file's content using HTTP. This avoids the overhead of encoding/decoding the binary, but is still copying the data again and again.

Still, the performance is orders of magnitude better than with IPC.